# Angular 2 Submit button outside of form

Tags: angular

my Submit button is outside of the form and i have no idea how to emit the submit event to the form. I tried the following:

```
 @ViewChild('myForm') myForm: any; // binding to my form

  clickSubmitButton(): void {
    this.myForm.submit(); 
  }
```

I get the following error:
this.myForm.submit is not a function.

Comment: Please post the exact error message.

Comment: What is `submit()` supposed to do anyway?

Comment: After i press the submit button in the form, it should show the validation messages for my inputs.

Comment: Angular2 valdiation messages are shown immediately and not only when the form is submitted. Therefore I still have troubles to understand what you actually try to accomplish.

Comment: Please show that template.

Answer (score 2):

This should work:

```
@ViewChild('myForm', {read: NgForm} ) myForm: any;
```

and

```
clickSubmitButton(): void {
  this.myForm.onSubmit(); 
}
```

Comment: hmm its not working for me.
i get again the following error: this.myForm.onSubmit is not a function

Answer (score 0):

You can use ElementRef

```
@ViewChild('myForm') myForm: ElementRef;
```

then

```
this.myForm.nativeElement.submit();
```

Don't forget import ElementRef

```
import { ElementRef } from '@angular/core';
```